# centos 7 save rsyslog on local and remote simultaneously

Tags: email, logging, centos, centos7, rsyslog

I am administrator of `postfix` mail server with `centos7`.

Today network administrator requests that all logs of email service must send to new log server that they run in network recently.

Sending logs to log server done by `rsyslog`, but my problem is email logs in `/var/log/maillog` does not saves the logs and its empty and I don`t have access to email logs in log server when I need them for troubleshoot.

How can I config `rsyslog` to save logs in `/var/log/maillog` and also send them to remote log server simultaneously? And if `rsyslog` does not have this ability is there another way to reach this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont be in a hury, I found it myself.
according to link below we can add destinations how many as we want by adding it in true format.
for example I added an additional destination by adding this line to /etc/rsyslog.conf:

mail.*             -/var/log/testemail

read link below:
https://www.ostechnix.com/setup-centralized-rsyslog-server-centos-7/